# Is it true (or not) that the familly $\exp(rx)$ geenates the space of continuous functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The family  $\{ e^{rx} : r \in \mathbb{R} \}$ is a linearly independent set in the space of function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ (I know how to prove that). But I am wondering if it could generate the vector space $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$, that is, the space of continuous functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$. I would say no, but  failed to find a counter example to that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector space spanned by these functions is very special. It is precisely the vector space of smooth functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfy a linear differential equation of the form

$$\sum_{i=0}^n c_i \frac{\partial^i}{(\partial x)^i} f(x) = 0$$

where the $c_i$ are constants such that the characteristic polynomial $\sum c_i t^i$ has distinct real roots. There are many, many ways that a continuous function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ can fail to have this property:

1. A sum of exponentials grows at most exponentially in $x$. Many functions grow faster than this, for example $f(x) = e^{e^x}$.
2. Most functions are not smooth, for example $|x|$.
3. Among smooth functions, functions of the above form have Taylor series whose coefficients grow exponentially (either getting bigger exponentially or smaller exponentially). There are many functions whose Taylor series do not grow like this; a simple example is a function like $\frac{1}{(1 + x^2)^2}$, whose Taylor series coefficients grow linearly, but we can also write down exotic functions like $\sum \frac{1}{(n!)^2} x^n$.
4. Among functions that satisfy differential equations of the above type with $p(t) = \sum c_i t^i$ arbitrary, the monic polynomial $p(t)$ of minimal degree with this property is unique, so we can take examples where the minimal such polynomial either has some complex roots or has repeated roots. In the first case we get functions like $\sin x, \cos x$ and in the second case we get functions like $x^2, x^2 e^x$.

A positive result along these lines, which is about what happens when you try to take the closure of the vector space spanned by a collection of functions with respect to a reasonable norm, is the general form of the [Stone-Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Comment: Many thanks for your very clear and complete answer.

Answer (score 3):

Pick any discontinuous function. $e^{rx}$ is continuous for any $r$, and so will be any linear combinations of them.

In addition, $e^{rx}$ is infinitely differentiable for any $r$. Since differentiation is linear, any linear sums of these functions will also be infinitely differentiable; you may pick $|x|$ as a counter-example, say.

Comment: Sorry... I forgot to mention that the functions are continuous.

Comment: @user125967 How's that do it for you?

Answer (score 1):

An easy example is the identity function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x$.

Comment: Ok, but how could you prove that ? thanks !

Comment: @user: any nonzero linear combination of exponential functions has infinitely many nonzero derivatives.